Implementing a permutation in Mathematica
The context of this question is to calculate DiracTrace in dimensional regularization, using a Scheme. The procedure is implemented in FeynCalc, but I want to implement explicitly. Let's consider a trace chain coming from some calculation, $\text{Tr}(\gamma_{\nu_1} \gamma_{\nu_2} \ldots \gamma_{\nu_{2n-1}} \gamma_{\nu_{2n}}\gamma_5)$, where $\gamma^5$ is the Chirality matrix. These technical details are not necessary. One way to handle this trace using the following substitution, which I want to implement in Mathematica :
$$
\text{Tr}(\gamma_{\nu_1} \gamma_{\nu_2} \ldots \gamma_{\nu_{2n-1}} \gamma_{\nu_{2n}}\gamma_5) = -4 i(g_{\nu_1\nu_2}g_{\nu_2\nu_3} \ldots g_{\nu_{2n-5}\nu_{2n-4}} \epsilon_{\nu_{2n-3}\nu_{2n-2}\nu_{2n-1}\nu_{2n}}) \pm \text{permutations of } \nu_1, \ldots \nu_{2n-1}
$$
where $\gamma$ are 4$\times$4 matrices (Dirac basis), $g$ are usual deltas, $\epsilon$ are Levi-civitas.
Lets consider some simple example: Using this formula, the following evaluation:
$$
Tr(\gamma_a\gamma_b\gamma_c\gamma_d\gamma^5)=-4i\epsilon_{abcd}
$$ Similarly, if you include two more, (odd are zero),
$$
Tr(\gamma_a\gamma_b\gamma_c\gamma_d\gamma_e\gamma_f\gamma^5)=-4 i \left(g^{ab} \overset{\text{}}{\epsilon }^{cdef}-g^{ac} \overset{\text{}}{\epsilon }^{bdef}+g^{ad} \overset{\text{}}{\epsilon
   }^{bcef}-g^{ae} \overset{\text{}}{\epsilon }^{bcdf}+g^{bc} \overset{\text{}}{\epsilon }^{adef}-g^{bd} \overset{\text{}}{\epsilon
   }^{acef}+g^{be} \overset{\text{}}{\epsilon }^{acdf}+g^{cd} \overset{\text{}}{\epsilon }^{abef}-g^{ce} \overset{\text{}}{\epsilon
   }^{abdf}+g^{de} \overset{\text{}}{\epsilon }^{abcf}\right)
$$
where the negative and positive signs come from anticommutations of $\gamma_\mu$. How to implement this in Mathematica? Unfortunately I have no idea so I'm unable to give any snippet.
For mathematica check, use FeynCalc, and
FCSetDiracGammaScheme["Larin"]
DiracTrace[GAD[a, b, c, d, e, f, 5], DiracTraceEvaluate -> True]


Note: For more complicated example, using 8 $\gamma$, the following is the result
$$
Tr(\gamma_a\gamma_b\gamma_c\gamma_d\gamma_e\gamma_f\gamma_h\gamma_j\gamma^5)=-4 i \left(\overset{\text{}}{\epsilon }^{efhj} g^{ad} g^{bc}-\overset{\text{}}{\epsilon }^{dfhj} g^{ae}
   g^{bc}+\overset{\text{}}{\epsilon }^{dehj} g^{af} g^{bc}-\overset{\text{}}{\epsilon }^{defj} g^{ah}
   g^{bc}+\overset{\text{}}{\epsilon }^{afhj} g^{de} g^{bc}-\overset{\text{}}{\epsilon }^{aehj} g^{df}
   g^{bc}+\overset{\text{}}{\epsilon }^{aefj} g^{dh} g^{bc}+\overset{\text{}}{\epsilon }^{adhj} g^{ef}
   g^{bc}-\overset{\text{}}{\epsilon }^{adfj} g^{eh} g^{bc}+\overset{\text{}}{\epsilon }^{adej} g^{fh}
   g^{bc}-\overset{\text{}}{\epsilon }^{efhj} g^{ac} g^{bd}+\overset{\text{}}{\epsilon }^{cfhj} g^{ae}
   g^{bd}-\overset{\text{}}{\epsilon }^{cehj} g^{af} g^{bd}+\overset{\text{}}{\epsilon }^{cefj} g^{ah}
   g^{bd}+\overset{\text{}}{\epsilon }^{dfhj} g^{ac} g^{be}-\overset{\text{}}{\epsilon }^{cfhj} g^{ad}
   g^{be}+\overset{\text{}}{\epsilon }^{cdhj} g^{af} g^{be}-\overset{\text{}}{\epsilon }^{cdfj} g^{ah}
   g^{be}-\overset{\text{}}{\epsilon }^{dehj} g^{ac} g^{bf}+\overset{\text{}}{\epsilon }^{cehj} g^{ad}
   g^{bf}-\overset{\text{}}{\epsilon }^{cdhj} g^{ae} g^{bf}+\overset{\text{}}{\epsilon }^{cdej} g^{ah}
   g^{bf}+\overset{\text{}}{\epsilon }^{defj} g^{ac} g^{bh}-\overset{\text{}}{\epsilon }^{cefj} g^{ad}
   g^{bh}+\overset{\text{}}{\epsilon }^{cdfj} g^{ae} g^{bh}-\overset{\text{}}{\epsilon }^{cdej} g^{af}
   g^{bh}+\overset{\text{}}{\epsilon }^{efhj} g^{ab} g^{cd}-\overset{\text{}}{\epsilon }^{bfhj} g^{ae}
   g^{cd}+\overset{\text{}}{\epsilon }^{behj} g^{af} g^{cd}-\overset{\text{}}{\epsilon }^{befj} g^{ah}
   g^{cd}+\overset{\text{}}{\epsilon }^{afhj} g^{be} g^{cd}-\overset{\text{}}{\epsilon }^{aehj} g^{bf}
   g^{cd}+\overset{\text{}}{\epsilon }^{aefj} g^{bh} g^{cd}-\overset{\text{}}{\epsilon }^{dfhj} g^{ab}
   g^{ce}+\overset{\text{}}{\epsilon }^{bfhj} g^{ad} g^{ce}-\overset{\text{}}{\epsilon }^{bdhj} g^{af}
   g^{ce}+\overset{\text{}}{\epsilon }^{bdfj} g^{ah} g^{ce}-\overset{\text{}}{\epsilon }^{afhj} g^{bd}
   g^{ce}+\overset{\text{}}{\epsilon }^{adhj} g^{bf} g^{ce}-\overset{\text{}}{\epsilon }^{adfj} g^{bh}
   g^{ce}+\overset{\text{}}{\epsilon }^{dehj} g^{ab} g^{cf}-\overset{\text{}}{\epsilon }^{behj} g^{ad}
   g^{cf}+\overset{\text{}}{\epsilon }^{bdhj} g^{ae} g^{cf}-\overset{\text{}}{\epsilon }^{bdej} g^{ah}
   g^{cf}+\overset{\text{}}{\epsilon }^{aehj} g^{bd} g^{cf}-\overset{\text{}}{\epsilon }^{adhj} g^{be}
   g^{cf}+\overset{\text{}}{\epsilon }^{adej} g^{bh} g^{cf}-\overset{\text{}}{\epsilon }^{defj} g^{ab}
   g^{ch}+\overset{\text{}}{\epsilon }^{befj} g^{ad} g^{ch}-\overset{\text{}}{\epsilon }^{bdfj} g^{ae}
   g^{ch}+\overset{\text{}}{\epsilon }^{bdej} g^{af} g^{ch}-\overset{\text{}}{\epsilon }^{aefj} g^{bd}
   g^{ch}+\overset{\text{}}{\epsilon }^{adfj} g^{be} g^{ch}-\overset{\text{}}{\epsilon }^{adej} g^{bf}
   g^{ch}+\overset{\text{}}{\epsilon }^{cfhj} g^{ab} g^{de}-\overset{\text{}}{\epsilon }^{bfhj} g^{ac}
   g^{de}+\overset{\text{}}{\epsilon }^{bchj} g^{af} g^{de}-\overset{\text{}}{\epsilon }^{bcfj} g^{ah}
   g^{de}-\overset{\text{}}{\epsilon }^{achj} g^{bf} g^{de}+\overset{\text{}}{\epsilon }^{acfj} g^{bh}
   g^{de}+\overset{\text{}}{\epsilon }^{abhj} g^{cf} g^{de}-\overset{\text{}}{\epsilon }^{abfj} g^{ch}
   g^{de}-\overset{\text{}}{\epsilon }^{cehj} g^{ab} g^{df}+\overset{\text{}}{\epsilon }^{behj} g^{ac}
   g^{df}-\overset{\text{}}{\epsilon }^{bchj} g^{ae} g^{df}+\overset{\text{}}{\epsilon }^{bcej} g^{ah}
   g^{df}+\overset{\text{}}{\epsilon }^{achj} g^{be} g^{df}-\overset{\text{}}{\epsilon }^{acej} g^{bh}
   g^{df}-\overset{\text{}}{\epsilon }^{abhj} g^{ce} g^{df}+\overset{\text{}}{\epsilon }^{abej} g^{ch}
   g^{df}+\overset{\text{}}{\epsilon }^{cefj} g^{ab} g^{dh}-\overset{\text{}}{\epsilon }^{befj} g^{ac}
   g^{dh}+\overset{\text{}}{\epsilon }^{bcfj} g^{ae} g^{dh}-\overset{\text{}}{\epsilon }^{bcej} g^{af}
   g^{dh}-\overset{\text{}}{\epsilon }^{acfj} g^{be} g^{dh}+\overset{\text{}}{\epsilon }^{acej} g^{bf}
   g^{dh}+\overset{\text{}}{\epsilon }^{abfj} g^{ce} g^{dh}-\overset{\text{}}{\epsilon }^{abej} g^{cf}
   g^{dh}+\overset{\text{}}{\epsilon }^{cdhj} g^{ab} g^{ef}-\overset{\text{}}{\epsilon }^{bdhj} g^{ac}
   g^{ef}+\overset{\text{}}{\epsilon }^{bchj} g^{ad} g^{ef}-\overset{\text{}}{\epsilon }^{bcdj} g^{ah}
   g^{ef}-\overset{\text{}}{\epsilon }^{achj} g^{bd} g^{ef}+\overset{\text{}}{\epsilon }^{acdj} g^{bh}
   g^{ef}+\overset{\text{}}{\epsilon }^{abhj} g^{cd} g^{ef}-\overset{\text{}}{\epsilon }^{abdj} g^{ch}
   g^{ef}+\overset{\text{}}{\epsilon }^{abcj} g^{dh} g^{ef}-\overset{\text{}}{\epsilon }^{cdfj} g^{ab}
   g^{eh}+\overset{\text{}}{\epsilon }^{bdfj} g^{ac} g^{eh}-\overset{\text{}}{\epsilon }^{bcfj} g^{ad}
   g^{eh}+\overset{\text{}}{\epsilon }^{bcdj} g^{af} g^{eh}+\overset{\text{}}{\epsilon }^{acfj} g^{bd}
   g^{eh}-\overset{\text{}}{\epsilon }^{acdj} g^{bf} g^{eh}-\overset{\text{}}{\epsilon }^{abfj} g^{cd}
   g^{eh}+\overset{\text{}}{\epsilon }^{abdj} g^{cf} g^{eh}-\overset{\text{}}{\epsilon }^{abcj} g^{df}
   g^{eh}+\overset{\text{}}{\epsilon }^{cdej} g^{ab} g^{fh}-\overset{\text{}}{\epsilon }^{bdej} g^{ac}
   g^{fh}+\overset{\text{}}{\epsilon }^{bcej} g^{ad} g^{fh}-\overset{\text{}}{\epsilon }^{bcdj} g^{ae}
   g^{fh}-\overset{\text{}}{\epsilon }^{acej} g^{bd} g^{fh}+\overset{\text{}}{\epsilon }^{acdj} g^{be}
   g^{fh}+\overset{\text{}}{\epsilon }^{abej} g^{cd} g^{fh}-\overset{\text{}}{\epsilon }^{abdj} g^{ce}
   g^{fh}+\overset{\text{}}{\epsilon }^{abcj} g^{de} g^{fh}\right)
$$


Unclear, you ask about the implementation of a substitution based on some formula and say that you do not have an idea. But you must have a clear idea how to use this substitution. We need this example, in order to test the substitution that we invent. So, can you please provide a Mathematica expression where you plan to use the substitution.

more details added, please check whether now it is clear
